# rxjs - Subject subscriber misses a value

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6

I have a `Subject` that is `next`'ed with a value before it has any subscribers - how do I make subscribers not miss values that got sent before the subscription?

Some code:

```
subject = new Subject<string>;
subject.next('value');

// at a later time
subject.subsribe(val => {...});
```

Comment: `subject = new ReplaySubject<string>(1);` where `1` is the number of values to be replayed.

Comment: Yes, that does the trick - please put it in an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a subject that will emit values to subscribers that subscriber after `next` has been called, you can use a `ReplaySubject`.

When creating a `ReplaySubject`, you can specify the number of `next` notifications that are to be replayed. To replay only one, you'd use:

```ts
subject = new ReplaySubject<string>(1);
```